# Numpy version when using both tensorflow and pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I am doing a project and I need to use both tensorflow and pandas together.

The primary issue i am having is with the numpy version. If I have the latest version of numpy then tensorflow throws an error:
"Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported"

If i downgrade numpy to 1.19.5 like the internet advises then importing pandas throws this error:
"numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. expected 88 from c header, got 80 from pyobject"

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you using conda or pip?

Comment: Set up a new virtualenv and clean install specific versions of numpy, pandas, and tensorflow.

Comment: the problem is likely from downgrading numpy rather than using a fresh build for all your libraries at the same time. try creating a new virtual env with 1.19.5. Pandas and other libraries are installed differently depending on the numpy installation & version so you can run into trouble swapping our numpy without a clean build. this is why conda and other package managers which explicitly handle binary and non-python dependencies are helpful.

Comment: @rpanai I am using conda but i have pip installed in conda so i can use both pip install... and conda install ...

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I will give that a shot thank you.

Comment: FYI pip does not do a great job managing non-python dependencies including compiled cython, C++, and other languages that are actually part of the numpy/scipy/pandas code bases. so if you install some things with conda and others with pip (or especially if you're later upgrading/downgrading with pip) that's probably the issue.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. However, i wasn't able to solve the problem. My solution ultimately was to use google collab.

Comment: Which `Tensorflow` version are you using?

Comment: Please try again by upgrading tensorflow version using `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow` in your system which will automatically install the latest and tensorflow compatible numpy version.